# How to add class to div having same name on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add a class to a div on a button click, I have the below code, but I cannot get the jquery working correctly:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.edit-btn').click(function()
        {
            $(this).closest('.edit-box').addClass('open');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col account">
  <strong>Account Settings</strong>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Profile Status</span>
    <p>status</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">
    
    <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
</div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Name</span>
    <p> name</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">
    
    <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
</div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Username</span> 
    <p>username</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">
    
    <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
</div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Bio</span>
    <p>bio</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">
    
    <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
</div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on the button will add a class to div i.e `.edit-box`. So only on the clicked button will add class to relevant div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code adds the `open` class to the `edit-box` div that comes after the button that is clicked.

It works by finding the parent of the button (i.e. the `flex-btn` container div), then getting the next element that has the class `edit-box`.

To see it working below I've added a background colour to the `.edit-box` and `.edit-box.open` divs so you can see it changing when the button is clicked:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.edit-box').addClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.edit-box {
  background: #ccffff;
}

.edit-box.open {
  background: #ccccff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col account">
  <strong>Account Settings</strong>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Profile Status</span>
    <p>status</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">

      <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Name</span>
    <p> name</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">

      <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Username</span>
    <p>username</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">

      <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Bio</span>
    <p>bio</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">

      <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand you correctly?

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.edit-btn').click(function()
        {
            //$('.edit-box').removeClass('open');
            $(this).closest('.col').find('.edit-box').addClass('open');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col account">
  <strong>Account Settings</strong>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Profile Status</span>
    <p>status</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">
    
    <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
</div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Name</span>
    <p> name</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">
    
    <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
</div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Username</span> 
    <p>username</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">
    
    <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
</div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>Bio</span>
    <p>bio</p>
    <div class="flex-btn front-btn">
    
    <button class="edit-btn">edit</button>
</div>
    <div class="edit-box">
      edit 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would add this to all of the divs that wrap around the buttons:

```
onclick="this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('open');"
```

That's not what you asked though, so here is how to get your thing working (using vanilla javascript):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.edit-btn').forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
                button.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add("open")
            })
        })
```

Comment: Yes I have try it with vanilla JS and it's working, but it should work with jQuery as well.